# How to properly decode or encode a string in python?

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding

I have the following string that is giving me the following error when I try to upload to a database:

```
String_from_source = 'STRINGÊ'
String_in_dataset = 'STRING\xe6'
```

When I try to decode or encode, I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

For example, I get this error for

```
'STRING\xe6'.encode()
'STRING\xe6'.decode()
'STRING\xe6'.encode('utf-8')
```

I've also tried:

```
'STRING\xe6'.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 17: unexpected end of data
```

Is there a way to eliminate this type of error once and for all? I really just want to exclude all special characters.

Comment: The `\xe6` byte is **not** UTF-8; that's a Latin-1 or Windows CP1252 byte. Using the correct codec is paramount.

Comment: What is the encoding of the source?

Comment: You may have some reading to do, like http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html and http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html and https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: The source is a CSV file, but I'm not sure the encoding that implicates.

Comment: @Chris: CSV files have no standard codec; it'll depend on the source instead. You haven't shown enough context to tell you exactly what codec it is. At a guess it'll be either Latin-1 or CP1252, but only because those two are more common.